# gulp build error on gulp sass task

Tags: css, npm, gulp-sass

When running on gulp build, I have encountered the following error in the CLI

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
 Error: E:\Projects\gulp\css\styles.min.css:546:10: Missed semicolon ←[90m 544 | ←[39m     b
ackground←[33m:←[39m ←[36m-ms-linear-gradient←[39m←[36m(top,  #5c710d 0%,#93b904 100%)←[39m←[33m;←[39m
 ←[90m 545 | ←[39m      background←[33m:←[39m ←[36mlinear-gradient←[39m←[36m(to bottom,  #5c710d 0%,#93b904 100%)←[39m←[33m;←[39m

←[31m←[1m>←[22m←[39m←[90m 546 | ←[39m   filter←[33m:←[39m progid ←[33m:←[39m←[36mDXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient←[39m←[36m(←[39m star
tColorstr=←[32m'#5c710d'←[39m, endColorstr=←[32m'#93b904'←[39m,GradientType=0 ←[36m)←[39m←[33m;←[39m
 ←[90m     | ←[39m              ←[31m←[1m^←[22m←[39m
 ←[90m 547 | ←[39m←[33m}←[39m
 ←[90m 548 | ←[39m←[33m.ui-overlay-c←[39m ←[33m{←[39m
```

Here is the browser specific css rule for gradient which i used in a stylesheet

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #5c710d 0%, #93b904 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#5c710d), color-stop(100%,#93b904)); 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #5c710d 0%,#93b904 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #5c710d 0%,#93b904 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #5c710d 0%,#93b904 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #5c710d 0%,#93b904 100%);
filter: progid :DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#5c710d', endColorstr='#93b904',GradientType=0 );
```

The used node packages are,

```
"devDependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.8.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1"
    "browser-sync": "^2.18.8",
    "del": "^2.2.2",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.1",
    "gulp-cache": "^0.4.6",
    "gulp-cssnano": "^2.1.2",
    "gulp-if": "^2.0.2",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^3.1.1",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.4.1",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.1.2",
    "gulp-useref": "^3.1.2",
    "run-sequence": "^1.2.2"
  }
```

and finally the gulp sass task

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('app/scss/**/*.scss') // Gets all files ending with .scss in app/scss and children dirs    
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError)) // Passes it through a gulp-sass, log errors to console
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css')) // Outputs it in the css folder
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({ // Reloading with Browser Sync
      stream: true
    }));
})
```

How to fix this error. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.. Thanks in advance.. And am using the node version of `node 4.4.4`

**The new error message**

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
 Error: E:\Projects\gulp\css\styles.min.css:1429:19: Unknown word ←[90m 1427 |
 ←[39m←[33m}←[39m
 ←[90m 1428 | ←[39m←[33m.list←[39m ←[33m.icn←[39m ←[33m{←[39m
←[31m←[1m>←[22m←[39m←[90m 1429 | ←[39m  margin-top←[33m:←[39m 10px←[33m;←[39m!important
 ←[90m      | ←[39m                      ←[31m←[1m^←[22m←[39m
 ←[90m 1430 | ←[39m←[33m}←[39m
 ←[90m 1431 | ←[39m←[33m.list←[39m ←[33m.txt←[39m ←[33m{←[39m
```

and also suggest how to read these type of errors.. Is there any CSS lint online for gulp-sass or any add on for atom package.. So that i can lint the CSS before gulp-build... Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra space in your filter property, between `progid`and `:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient`, which cause the `missed semicolon` error.

Also, with your Gulp plugins, you have `gulp-autoprefixer`. Add it to your Gulp `sass` task (before `.pipe(sourcemaps.write())`) :

```
.pipe(autoprefixer())
```

and don't write nothing more than :

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #5c710d 0%,#93b904 100%);
```

and Autoprefixer will do the job and will add the expected prefixes (depending of your settings).

Comment: Wow..great  that error is gone.. Thank you very much.. But, got a new error .. Please find the new error message on the question...

Comment: It seems like this new error happen on other part of your code.

Comment: I don't understand why you get dirty error message format like this. You should get something more readable, and clearly more helpfull.